# Laravel Auth::attempt() is not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have added my code and problem..no one is available there to respond me .. please help me to solve this !

http://laravel.io/forum/10-25-2015-laravel-5120-lts-fails-to-authenticate

I dono what's wrong with laravel,

I have the following functions in same controller

```
  public function signup()
    {
         $user=new User();
 $user->email=Input::get('email');
 $user->password=Hash::make(Input::get('Password'));
 $user->username=$username;
 $user->save();
// self authenticating user 
Auth::attempt(['email'=>Input::get('email'),'password'=>Input::get('Password')],true);
       return Auth::user();
    }
```

the above Auth::attempt() is working fine but the next method to this signup is

```
  public function login()
{
if( Auth::attempt(['email'=>Input::get('email'),'password'=>Input::get('password')],true))
   {
      return Auth::user();
   }
   else
   {
      echo "failed";
   }
  }
```

here the Auth is not working i dono y.. no errors with form

Comment: `Auth::check` only checks if a user is logged in. Therefore this is not a solution. At first. Please provide your code within this question (and not just excerpts).

Comment: Don't include important question content by linking to outside resources, because they may become unavailable over time and the question will lose its meaning for future readers. Instead, include the code within the question.

Comment: @Prakash can you show me your method ?

Comment: `public function login()
    { 
        if(Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'),'password'=>Input::get('password') )))
        {
            echo "done";
        }
        

       if(Input::get('remember'))
          $remember=true;
      else
        $remember=false;
        else
        {
            $errors[0]="Login failed !";
            echo "failed";
            // return redirect()->back()->with('errors',$errors)->with('action','login');
        }`

Answer (score 0):

- Did you make sure to give your inputs a `name` attribute? Laravels *Input/Request* Facades accesses them by the name, not id or class.
- Have you tried the default [AuthController](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#authentication-quickstart) ?

Comment: I have name attribute in my forms.

Comment: Try out the default shipped AuthController I linked. If it works, then your custom controller is doing something wrong.

Comment: But the same is working on my signup_controller Auth::attempt ...`     Auth::attempt(['email'=>Input::get('email'),'password'=>Input::get('Password')],true);`

Comment: I'd suggest you try XDebug or any Zend Debugger to trace a breakpoint on the attempt method and see where anything goes wrong.